Can the following optimization problem be reformulated into a standard form convex problem?
I have the following optimization problem given:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max \quad & E \cdot p - c_A * A - c_h * h - c_C * C \\
\textrm{subject to:} \quad & v \leq \log(h) \\
& E \leq v^3 \cdot A \\
& E \geq C \\
& A, C, E, v, h \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
with $A, C, E, v, h$ as variables
and $p, c_A, c_h, c_C$ as positive parameters.
I would have a convex optimization problem if not for the constraint $E \leq v^3 \cdot A$.
Is there a way to reformulate that problem so that it becomes convex?
The only idea I have is to take the logarithm of $E \leq v^3 \cdot A$ so that $\log(E) \leq 3 \cdot \log(v) + \log(A)$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max \quad & E \cdot p - c_A * A - c_h * h - c_C * C \\
\textrm{subject to:} \quad & v \leq \log(h) \\
& \log(E) \leq 3 \cdot \log(v) + \log(A) \\
& E \geq C \\
& A, C, E, v, h \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
But this would, of course, remove that $v,A,E$ could be zero, due to the logarithm and the constraint is still not convex.
Is there another option to reformulate the original problem to make it convex?

Can you clarify what the optimization variables are?

Of course, my bad, $A, C, E, v, h$ are the variables.
